# Definite integral including natural log, cosine, and hyperbolic sine

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Here is an integral question I have, I am solving some other problems like this but I am stumped on this one:

$$\int_0^{\pi+1}\frac {\ln(\cos(x+1))}{\sinh(x^2)}dx$$

I used some methods such as residues and trying identies (i.e. $\ln(\sin(x/2))$, but I have not had much luck. How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do not waste your time on random integrals like this, since chances are there is no closed form or nice expression for this. If you really need to compute this integral for some purpose, the right way out is to find an appropriate [numerical quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) capable of handling the singularity at the origin.